# Completely hide column when it starts to overflow

Tags: html, css, grid, overflow

I am building an application that involves a grid of shapes on the right of the page. This grid consists of columns of 5 squares each with the height and width of the viewport height divided by 5 (taking up the whole height of the viewport together). There are normally 4 rows of shapes (each row has a width of 80vh in total).

I need to split the page into two sections: 40vw is dedicated to content on the left and a maximum of 60vw is dedicated to the grid. The grid on the right cannot overflow into the content.

The problem I'm facing is that if the height of the container is too great, the shapes will overflow the designated 60vw. I was wondering if there were a way to completely hide a column if the grid overflows the 60vw. I tried hiding the overflow but this hides part of the column that is overflowing as opposed to the whole column.

I attached the code I'm working with below together with some annotations to illustrate the problem.

Thank you for taking the time to go through this :),

Andrei.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="content"></div>
            <div class="shapes">
                    <div class="grid-container">
                        <div class="grid-col">
                            <div class="grid-item">1</div>
                            <div class="grid-item">2</div>
                            <div class="grid-item">3</div>
                            <div class="grid-item">4</div>
                            <div class="grid-item">5</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="grid-col">
                            <div class="grid-item">1</div>
                            <div class="grid-item">2</div>
                            <div class="grid-item">3</div>
                            <div class="grid-item">4</div>
                            <div class="grid-item">5</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="grid-col">
                            <div class="grid-item">1</div>
                            <div class="grid-item">2</div>
                            <div class="grid-item">3</div>
                            <div class="grid-item">4</div>
                            <div class="grid-item">5</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="grid-col">
                            <div class="grid-item">1</div>
                            <div class="grid-item">2</div>
                            <div class="grid-item">3</div>
                            <div class="grid-item">4</div>
                            <div class="grid-item">5</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
.container {
    display: grid;
    height: 100vh;
    grid-template-columns: 40vw 60vw;
}

.shapes {
    display: grid;
    justify-content: right;
    background-color: teal;
    width: 60vw;
}

.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template: 20vh / 20vh 20vh 20vh 20vh;
    width: 80vh;
}

.grid-item {
    outline: 2px solid #000;
    outline-offset: -2px;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}

.grid-item {
    height: 20vh;
    text-align: center;
}

.content {
    background-color: blanchedalmond;
}
```

[Works in image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgKmd.png)

[Does not work in image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6lVL.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem starts when the width of the right hand side is less than that of 4 squares i.e. when: 60vw < 80vh - that is when vw/vh < 4/3

we can test for this in CSS by using a media query on the viewport's aspect ratio

```
@media (max-aspect-ratio: 4/3)
```

After that there are problems when 60vw is less than 60vh, 40vh and 20vh.

This snippet tests for all of these cases and hides the relevant column.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-template-columns: 40vw 60vw;
}

.shapes {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: right;
  background-color: teal;
  width: 60vw;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 20vh / 20vh 20vh 20vh 20vh;
  width: 80vh;
}

.grid-item {
  outline: 2px solid #000;
  outline-offset: -2px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.grid-item {
  height: 20vh;
  text-align: center;
}

.content {
  background-color: blanchedalmond;
}

@media (max-aspect-ratio: 4/3) {
  .grid-container .grid-col:nth-child(1) {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}

@media (max-aspect-ratio: 1/1) {
  .grid-container .grid-col:nth-child(2) {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}

@media (max-aspect-ratio: 2/3) {
  .grid-container .grid-col:nth-child(3) {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}

@media (max-aspect-ratio: 1/3) {
  .grid-container .grid-col:nth-child(4) {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="shapes">
    <div class="grid-container">
      <div class="grid-col">
        <div class="grid-item">1</div>
        <div class="grid-item">2</div>
        <div class="grid-item">3</div>
        <div class="grid-item">4</div>
        <div class="grid-item">5</div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-col">
        <div class="grid-item">1</div>
        <div class="grid-item">2</div>
        <div class="grid-item">3</div>
        <div class="grid-item">4</div>
        <div class="grid-item">5</div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-col">
        <div class="grid-item">1</div>
        <div class="grid-item">2</div>
        <div class="grid-item">3</div>
        <div class="grid-item">4</div>
        <div class="grid-item">5</div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-col">
        <div class="grid-item">1</div>
        <div class="grid-item">2</div>
        <div class="grid-item">3</div>
        <div class="grid-item">4</div>
        <div class="grid-item">5</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```